# "gomaasapi: got error back from server: 403 FORBIDDEN" error while bootstrapping

Tags: server, juju, maas

I am investigating MAAS with Juju on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. (also tried 13.10...)

I have set up my server(s) using various tutorials, but I keep getting 403 errors when bootstrapping Juju.

I have tried it as root and as the local administrator (I created them both in the OS and in the web UI for MAAS. Also I used the proper keys in the corresponding `.juju/environments.yaml`). Everytime I keep getting `2014-03-04 15:20:50 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 cannot start bootstrap instance: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 403 FORBIDDEN` errors.

Is there anyone who can give me a clue, so I can continue my installation?

Setup information:

- Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
- MAAS 1.4+bzr1693+dfsg-0ubuntu2.2~ctools0
- Juju 1.16.6

Answer (score 4):

OP Posted:

> I am using plain PCs to test the setup. Therefore I am forced to use WOL instead of e.g. IPMI/iDRAC etc. It seems that when you configure the node as using WOL, you have (!!) to enter the MAC address explicitly.

Doc reference:

- http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html#manually-add-nodes

Comment: It appears you also have to enter the MAC address for the node added when using PXE boot, in case you use WOL.